# Factory function for dataclass fields

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm making a library where I want to take advantage of metadata on the fields of a dataclass.

To get my desired results, I can write the dataclass like the following:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = field(
        metadata={'my_metadata': {'my_required_key': "c"}}
    )
    b: dict[str, str] = field(
        metadata={'my_metadata': {'my_required_key': "d"}}, default_factory=dict
    )
```

This seems like a lot of boilerplate, especially if I want to make many classes with many fields like this. I was thinking I could write a factory function to wrap `dataclass.field` and help reduce the amount of repetition.

However, I can't seem to get the type parameters right for calling into `dataclass.field` and proper value for the response type is a mystery to me. What I have so far:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, MISSING, _MISSING_TYPE
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Callable

_T = TypeVar("_T")


def myfield(
    my_required_key: str,
    *,
    default: Union[_MISSING_TYPE, _T] = MISSING,
    default_factory: Union[_MISSING_TYPE, Callable[[], _T]] = MISSING
) -> _T:
    return field(  # type: ignore
        metadata={'my_metadata': {'my_required_key': my_required_key}},
        default=default,
        default_factory=default_factory,
    )
```

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = myfield("c")
    b: dict[str, str] = myfield("d", default_factory=dict)
```

This code will pass `mypy` validation, but PyCharm doesn't seem to like it, reporting that:

> Mutable default 'myfield("d", default_factory=dict)' is not allowed. Use 'default_factory'`

I'm okay with ignoring the PyCharm error, as the class does appear to function correctly, and I use `mypy` in my CICD which seems to be cool with it.

As for the return type, I currently have `myfield(...) -> _T`. I feel like the signature should look more like `myfield(...) -> Field[_T]`, but `mypy` rejects that idea, and reports:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Field[<nothing>]", variable has type "int")
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Field[Dict[_KT, _VT]]", variable has type "Dict[str, str]")
```

I'm also not sure about how to type the `default` and `default_factory` parameters. Without the `# type: ignore` I will get:

```
error: No overload variant of "field" matches argument types "Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]", "Union[_MISSING_TYPE, _T]", "Union[_MISSING_TYPE, Callable[[], _T]]"
note: Possible overload variants:
note:     def [_T] field(*, default: _T, init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]] = ...) -> _T
note:     def [_T] field(*, default_factory: Callable[[], _T], init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]] = ...) -> _T
note:     def field(*, init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]] = ...) -> Any
```

I see other libraries have gone about reducing the boiler-plate by making a factory method only return the metadata dictionary. i.e.

```
@dataclass
class Fizz:
    a: int = field(metadata=myfield("c"))
    b: dict[str, str] = field(metadata=myfield("d"), default_factory=dict)
```

This still feels a bit ugly to me, but maybe this is the way to go.

Any help or ideas for cleaning this up would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already "truncating" the full signature of `fields` in your wrapper; I would just take that further:

```
def myfield(required_key: str, **kwargs):
    kwargs['metadata'] = dict(my_metadata=dict(my_required_key=required_key))
    return field(**kwargs)
```

This level of indirection, though, appears to prevent `mypy` from checking that the arguments passed to `myfield` have the correct types expected by `field`.

---

Or, in the spirit of "Prefer composition over inheritance", just write a function that creates the correct metadata to use as an argument to `field`. This lets your users call `field` directly, saving you from having to duplicate its [intricate hinting](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/dataclasses.pyi#L111).

```
def make_metadata(required_key: str):
    return dict(my_metadata(dict(my_required_key=required_key)))


@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = field(metadata=make_metadata("c"))
    b: dict[str, str] = field(metadata=make_metadata("d"), default_factory=dict)
```

Still some boilerplate, but less of it.

At some level, there is an inescapable trade-off involving the amount of static typing you can bolt onto a dynamically-typed language, or rather how that typing is bolted on. You'll see the use of `overload` in the type hinting for `field`, but `overload` doesn't *do* anything. It's just a place to park annotations in the source code for `mypy` to analyze; it doesn't change its target in anyway (in fact, it just discards it, as the intention is to redefine it later). That's why the hinted variants are just "implemented" with `...`, because the body doesn't matter: you'll never use the `function` object being defined, only the final, undecorated function.

---

I would have suggested something like just setting the metadata directly on a `Field` object, except the metadata is the only attribute that involves more than just a [simple assignment in `Field.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/dataclasses.py#L254):

```
def __init__(self, default, default_factory, init, repr, hash, compare,
             metadata):
    [...]
    self.metadata = (_EMPTY_METADATA
                     if metadata is None else
                     types.MappingProxyType(metadata))
    [...]
```

Backpedalling from "Prefer composition...", it would be nice if `Field` were exposed directly, so that you could subclass it like

```
class MyField(Field):
    def set_metadata(self, key: str):
        self.metadata = types.MappingProxyType(dict(...))
        return self
```

and use

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = Field().set_metadata("c")
    b: dict[str, str] = Field(default_factory=dict).set_metadata("d")
```

Not that I'm *advocating* direct use of `Field` like this, but....

Also, `MappingProxyType` is only used, as far as I know, to make the metadata read-only. If you don't mind relaxing that part of the `Field` object...

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = field()
    make_metadata(a, "c")
    b: dict[str, str] = field(default_factory=dict)
    make_metadata(b, "d")
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, that’s certainly one extreme to go about it. Ideally I’d like it to be typed such that tools like mypy can show users if they’re calling the function incorrectly. I’d prefer the heavy boilerplate to untyped code.

Comment: Maybe there’s a trick with pyi stub files that could help me out here.

Comment: Ok, updated with some meandering thoughts on how to preserve the direct use of `field` instead of replacing it with a wrapper function. I'm a firm believer that it's OK to leave *some* responsibilities with the end user if it means keeping the implementation simpler.

Comment: These are some great options, I’ll need some time to digest it all! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Return type of `myfield`**

With regards to whether the return type should be `_T` or `Field[_T]`, it's notable that the typeshed library -- the repository of stub files that all major type-checkers use for checking the standard library -- just uses `_T` as the return type. In fact, there's a very illuminating comment in the source code on why that's the case:

```
# NOTE: Actual return type is 'Field[_T]', but we want to help type checkers
# to understand the magic that happens at runtime.
```

If it's good enough for typeshed, I'd say it's probably good enough for you!

**PyCharm**

At this stage, I'm annoyed enough with PyCharm's buggy type-checking that I might advise you to just ignore the annoying message about mutable default fields. But, that's not particularly helpful, since you're writing a library, and many of the users of your library will be using PyCharm. Unfortunately, it looks like there's not really a good solution, as this is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46653) that's much broader than this specific issue when it comes to PyCharm's type-checking of dataclass `field`s.

**type: ignore**

I don't see much wrong with having a single `# type: ignore` in your code. No type-checker's perfect, and it's all an approximation anyway, since Python's fundamentally a dynamic language. For MyPy, you can be more specific in telling it to only ignore certain kinds of errors (the --show-error-codes option is very useful for learning which kinds of MyPy exceptions are being raised). In this case, the error is a MyPy `call-overload` error, so you can alter your `# type: ignore` to `# type: ignore[call-overload]`. (Sadly, having that kind of syntax -- even in a *comment*! -- will play havoc with PyCharm's linter. I have honestly no idea why.)

**References**

Here's the [full hint](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/92aecadf6b0f2ef69a0b4a22afa60342fdb60942/stdlib/dataclasses.pyi#L108) for the `dataclasses.field` function as of 13/08/2021:

```
# NOTE: Actual return type is 'Field[_T]', but we want to help type checkers
# to understand the magic that happens at runtime.
if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    @overload  # `default` and `default_factory` are optional and mutually exclusive.
    def field(
        *,
        default: _T,
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
        kw_only: bool = ...,
    ) -> _T: ...
    @overload
    def field(
        *,
        default_factory: Callable[[], _T],
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
        kw_only: bool = ...,
    ) -> _T: ...
    @overload
    def field(
        *,
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
        kw_only: bool = ...,
    ) -> Any: ...

else:
    @overload  # `default` and `default_factory` are optional and mutually exclusive.
    def field(
        *,
        default: _T,
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
    ) -> _T: ...
    @overload
    def field(
        *,
        default_factory: Callable[[], _T],
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
    ) -> _T: ...
    @overload
    def field(
        *,
        init: bool = ...,
        repr: bool = ...,
        hash: bool | None = ...,
        compare: bool = ...,
        metadata: Mapping[Any, Any] | None = ...,
    ) -> Any: ...
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I think I can combine the overloads like that in a `.pyi` file and combine that with @chepner 's answer about truncating the arguments to just using `**kwargs` in that actual `.py` file.

Comment: @flakes — that sounds like a great idea. From my perspective, I think our two answers should work really well together.